# Обращение к нескольким элементам с одинаковым id

Tags: javascript

Добрый день. Не могу вывести несколько `div`, работает только первый.
Как вообще сделать вывод нескольких элементов?

```js
var el = document.getElementById('graph'); // get canvas

var options = {
  percent: el.getAttribute('data-percent') || 25,
  size: el.getAttribute('data-size') || 220,
  lineWidth: el.getAttribute('data-line') || 15,
  rotate: el.getAttribute('data-rotate') || 0
}

var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var span = document.createElement('span');
span.textContent = options.percent + '%';

if (typeof(G_vmlCanvasManager) !== 'undefined') {
  G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvas);
}

var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = canvas.height = options.size;

el.appendChild(span);
el.appendChild(canvas);

ctx.translate(options.size / 2, options.size / 2); // change center
ctx.rotate((-1 / 2 + options.rotate / 180) * Math.PI); // rotate -90 deg

//imd = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 240, 240);
var radius = (options.size - options.lineWidth) / 2;

var drawCircle = function(color, lineWidth, percent) {
  percent = Math.min(Math.max(0, percent || 1), 1);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2 * percent, false);
  ctx.strokeStyle = color;
  ctx.lineCap = 'round'; // butt, round or square
  ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth
  ctx.stroke();
};

drawCircle('#efefef', options.lineWidth, 100 / 100);
drawCircle('#555555', options.lineWidth, options.percent / 100);
```

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  margin: 80px;
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
span {
  color: #555;
  display: block;
  line-height: 220px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 220px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 100;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="chart" id="graph" data-percent="88"></div>
<div class="chart" id="graph" data-percent="100"></div>
```

Comment: Согласно стандарту HTML, ID должен быть **уникален** в рамках всего документа. Поэтому, идеологически верный ответ на ваш вопрос -- **никак**. (Но при желании можно использовать какой-нибудь костыль на основе обхода DOM, если речь о чистом JS.)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev если к id подставлять цифры, то он будет уникальным.

Comment: Да, но это не имеет ничего общего с вашим вопросом

Comment: а зачем там вообще `Id` если уже есть `class="chart"`?

Comment: @Grundy тоже хотел спросить у него) зачем ему `id`, если есть класс `chart`))

Comment: @gm-111 если подставлять цифры к id, то получится как раз на каждый элемент - свой уникальный идентификатор, как было написано в самом первом комментарии. Чтоб вывести каждый такой элемент - придется пройтись в цикле подставляя к имени ту самую цифру............. или же обратиться к элементам через класс... правда на чистом js все равно придется в цикле или map всей коллекции что-то присвоить, вроде бы

Comment: Если Вы не планируете поддерживать IE8 и ниже, воспользуйтесь выборкой не по ID, а по классу через [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) или лучше [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) как подсказывает @DmitriySimushev

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, `document.querySelectorAll` не?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev наверное) я ж не профи)) мне этот язык неведом особо.... только вот как их всех отобразить одной командой или, допустим стиль присвоить? `document.querySelectorAll('.mySuperClass').style.backgroundColor = 'red'`  вроде как не сработает.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, никак, только циклом, пускай даже `.forEach`

Comment: @Grundy ну так я об этом, собственно, и сказал. Че меня Дмитрий смущает? А автору енто самое и нужно, если я понял

Comment: @gm-111 Удалите айдишники. Выберите элементы по классу через `querySelectorAll`....Пробегитесь по выбранной  коллекции, присвоив нужные свойства (или что вы там хотите с ними делать). Всё

Answer (score 4):

Вам абсолютно правильно делают замечание, что `ID` в рамках страницы должен быть уникальным. Однако, если прямо-таки кровь из носу нужно выбрать именно такие элементы, тогда воспользуйтесь следующим селектором для выборки элементов:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[id="header"]');
```